# Id counting in TYPO3 menu using register:count_MENUOBJ

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I made the menu in `TYPO3` for `bootstrap` framework. Everything working just fine, but I have problem with counting the `id` element using register:count_MENUOBJ. The whole menu is constructed from two parts - main menu and sub menu:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = HMENU
page.10.special = directory
page.10.entryLevel = 0
page.10.maxItems = 6
page.10 {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {

    wrap = <div class="row"><ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right" id="myTab" role="tablist">|</ul></div>
    noBlur = 1
    expAll = 1
        NO {
    ATagTitle.field = title
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    accessKey = 1
        }

        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    linkWrap= |
    ATagParams = role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item-{register:count_MENUOBJ}"
    ATagParams.insertData = 1
    ATagBeforeWrap = 1
    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }

        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
        ACTIFSUB {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active dropdown">|</li>
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }

        CURIFSUB < .IFSUB
        CURIFSUB = 1
        CURIFSUB {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active dropdown">|</li>
    }
  }
}

page.20 = HMENU
page.20.special = directory
page.20.entryLevel = 0
page.20.maxItems = 6
page.20 {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
    wrap = <div class="row"><div class="tab-content">|</div></div>   
    noBlur = 1 
    expAll = 1
    NO.doNotShowLink = 1
  }
  # second level
  2.maxItems = 5
  2 = TMENU
  2.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="tab-pane fade in active pull-right" id="item-{register:count_MENUOBJ}"><nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right submenu" role="navigation"><ul class="nav navbar-nav in">|</ul></nav></div>
  2.stdWrap.wrap.insertData = 1
  2{
    expAll = 1
    NO{
      ATagTitle.field = title
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }
    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB{
      ATagTitle.field = title
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }
  }
}
```

In the first menu block links has the correct value: `data-target="#item-1"`, `data-target="#item-2"` etc..

In the second block the all links are generated in this form: `id="item-5"` staring and ending on `item-5`

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you check my answer ? I'm curious if that is a valid suggestion ... the question has been checked a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register:count_MENUOBJ` is counting the menu-items in the context where it's used.

In the first menu it's used in the context of the main-items and therefore counting in the natural order of the menu-items like an index. This might be the reason that the function of `register:count_MENUOBJ` is still confusing, even usable in that context.

In the second menu `register:count_MENUOBJ` is used in the context of the sub-menu items and counting the sub-items on level 2. So if on level two are 3 sub-items the register is 3. If 5 sub-items it's 5. In this context `register:count_MENUOBJ` is not usable as index as the amount of sub-items never reflects the expected value according to the question.

Therefore to get unique id's it's common practice to use `p{field:uid}` for pages or for content-elements `c{field:uid}`.

Example:

```
...
NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li id="nav-main-p{field:uid}">|</li>
NO.wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
...
```

Another alternative is to use `register:count_MENUOBJ` in the second menu also on the first level. Question if the menu in the question would have the required properties then.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MenuProcessor` instead of `HMENU`. I always had problems with the custom rendering of `HMENU` and than i turned to `MenuProcessor` because the `html` markup may be created directly in `fluid`.

**Typoscript:**

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  ...

  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    10 {
         as = navigationMain
    }
  }


}
```

**FLUID:**

```
<f:for each="{navigationMain}" as="menuItem">
   <!-- There you have access to menu items -->
</f:for>
```

Documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/MainMenuCreation/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

In general @David already gave all relevant information.

For clarification and as hint for an easier implementation:

In your example you used the count register in `page.20.2.stdWrap.wrap`. this Wrap is executed in context of second level menu, but after the menu is allready generated, so it contains the number of elements in this menu level.
You need to use the count register in first level, and so it is a wrap to the second level you can use it in `.1.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub`, as you have no content in first level it will be a wrap only for the second level menu.

---

And also mentioned from @David:
You also could use the `uid`s from the pages itself.
Use it in `page.10`, and in `page.20.2` you could use the field `pid` **from any page on that level**.
As you want to use it out of the context of a `menuItem` you might get the problem: there is no real field `pid`. Either you do the wrap on the first page/ menuItem (hint: optionsplit) or do it in the first level again.
(I doubt that for `.1.stdWrap` you are in the context of the first level page, so you could use field `uid`.)

Answer (score -1):

you probably have to insert the following (not tested):

```
page.15 = RESTORE_REGISTER
```

just before page.20 = HMENU ... normally used in combination with **`LOAD_REGISTER`** but it looks as if your second HMENU has the count_MENUOBJ stuck at the last value of the first ...